# JS run function from constructor after object instantiation

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to do this:

```
var hammer = new Hammer(); // create a new instance
hammer(nail); // really call Hammer.prototoype.hit(object);
```

I can figure it out on a raw object, but not when creating a new instance of an object. This is what I am running into:

```
function Hammer(options) {
  this.config = options.blah;
  this.hit(/* ? */);
  return this;
}

Hammer.prototype.hit = function(obj) {
  // ...
}
```

When I call the constructor, I want to pass in special options - not what nail to hit. However, when I call it later, I want to pass in a nail. I'm missing something.

Comment: `function Hammer(object) { this.hit(object); }`?

Comment: But how do I separate it from the constructor function?

Comment: How would you do it with a raw object?

Comment: @dc2, `hammer.hit(object);` then?

Comment: Yes - but i'm looking to see if there's a shortcut so I don't have to expose `hit`. That's the point of this question. If there isn't, well that's why I asked if its possible. :)

Comment: For example, in jQuery, you just say `$(selector)`. But then jQuery doesn't deal with prototyped objects...

Comment: but `$()` is the constructor; it constructs a jQuery object. You don't do `var $ = new jQuery()`...

Comment: Ah - so it constructs a new one every single time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to not create a constructor function at all:

```
var hammer = newHammer();

hammer(nail);

hammer.clean();

function newHammer(options) {
    var config = options.blah;

    hit.clean = clean;

    return hit;

    function hit(obj) {
        // ...
    }

    function clean() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

To me, this is a much cleaner solution than messing around with constructors and prototypes.

Comment: True, but then could you create two different hammers with different properties? I might want my first hammer to be blue and the other one red!

Comment: @dc2 of course; every object returned by the `hammer` factory is a new one.

Comment: Well, that makes you a boss, then.

Comment: Eh - in trying this, one side effect is that you can't then access any other functions. How could I do `hammer(nail)` as well as `hammer.clean()`? Again `jQuery` seems to accomplish this.

Comment: @dc2 I updated my answer showing how to call `hammer.clean`. This is the way jQuery does it as well.

Comment: Brilliant - we both figured that out at the same time :)